# VBA function syntax

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, syntax

I am writing functions with the following equation:

1. `P = 10 ^ (A - B9 / ( T + C ))`
2. `Z = C * Exp ( -k * t)`

I am using the following syntax:

Answer 1:

```vb
Function P(a As Integer, b As Integer, c As Integer, t As Integer) As Integer
    P = (10 ^ a) / 10 ^ (b / (t + c))
End Function
```

Answer 2:

```vb
Function Z(c As Integer, k As Integer, t As Integer) As Integer
    Z = c / Exp(-k * t)
End Function
```

The answers are not coming out as accurate.

Please let me know where I am lacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equations are different from the original, you should also post the expected result from certain numbers, try this:

```
Function P(a As Integer, b As Integer, c As Integer, t As Integer) As Integer
    P = 10 ^ (a - b / (t + c))
End Function

Function Z(c As Integer, k As Integer, t As Integer) As Integer
    Z = c * Exp(-k * t)
End Function
```

Also you must take into account the max value that holds the `Integer` that is: `32767` so the program will overflow when that variable exceeds that value, you can read more about data limits [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary)

Comment: Hey,  Thanks a ton!
Because of you I made it correctly.